# DynamoDB Query with sort key and partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using JS SDK with DynamoDB to fetch data.

I am able to fetch data from my table using simple query with `partition key` and `sort key`.

My sort key `sk` has records -

> `Year#Batch#Rate`

If I pass `var sk = "2006#CSE#90";` it returns all of records matching this,

**Requirement -** How can I get all products with `year 2006` , `Batch CSE` AND `Rate =>90`

```
readItem_pbro(){
  console.log("inside pbro");
  var table2 = "pbro";
  var pk = "1";
  var sk = "2006#CSE#90";

  var params2 = {
      TableName: table2,
      Key:{
          "pk": pk,
          "sk": sk
      }
  };
```

**Edit 1 ::** Created a different column for score/rate as score. It is numeric.

Now my query in `JS` is -
but I am getting error - `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`

```
readItem_score_filter(){
  console.log("inside pbro");
  var table2 = "pbro"; 
  var pk = "1";  // string
  var sk = "2006#CSE"; // string
  var score = 90; //number

  var params2 = {
      TableName: table2,
      Key:{
          "pk": pk,
          "sk": sk,
          FilterExpression:'score >=:score',
      }
  };
```

what is wrong in my `FilterExpression`.

**Edit 2 ::** Added Key condition Expression but issue still remains the same

Error: `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`
Here is my complete function now:

```
readItem_score_filter(){
  console.log("inside pbro");
  var table2 = "pbro";
  var pk = "1"; //string
  var sk = "2006#CSE"; // string
  var score = 90; //number

  var params2 = {
      TableName: table2,
      Key:{
          "pk": pk,
          "sk": sk,
          "score": score,
           KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :pk AND sk=:sk',
           FilterExpression: "score >=:score",
      }
  };
  this.user.docClient.get(params2, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
}
```

Screenshot of table attached incase you need to see::

[image]

Comment: "2006#CSE#90" - is this value of one attribute (column) or 3 attributes?

Comment: this is sort key,  one column

Comment: year , batch and rate are different columns or just one column?

Comment: all in one column

Answer (score 0):

If "2006#CSE#90" this is the value of sort key column  then you cant do anything at Dynamodb level..

comparings like this can be done through regular expressions but DynamoDB doesn't support Regular Expressions.

you simply need to get results and then seperate these values and compare ..

Updated :- use different column for score.

And use `Filter Expression` to get records having rate more than 90.

I dont know python , but still am trying here

```
var params2 = {
TableName: "pbro",
KeyConditionExpression: "pk = :pk AND sk =:sk", 
FilterExpression: "score >= :score"
```

};

Comment: college ID is Partition key , Batch#Course is sort key , now where do i place score :(

Comment: Use filter expressuons on score/rate column

Comment: ok, i have separated the column,  named it score , can you use my code and update your answer please

Comment: please note score column in neither partition nor sort key

Comment: I have done edit 1 in my question, you can have a look

Comment: you also need to use KeyConditionExpression where you will use main 2 keys

Comment: can you update that in your answer, i am new and confused

Comment: check now.. pk should be your partition key , sk should be your sort key

Comment: Hii, I have done edit 2, error still remains the same, i have copied my entire function. Can you guide me what is still missing